# Not able to pick ancestor Tag attribute value using XLST

Tags: xslt

Source XML for the XSLT issue statement.

```
<College>
    <Student> 
            <Name>ABC</Name> 
            <Age>25<Age>
    </Student>
    <Result> 
            <account> 
               <accountNumber>1111</accountNumber>
            </account> 
            <account> 
               <accountNumber>2222</accountNumber> 
            </account>
    </Result> 
    </College>
```

Current issue is that I am unable to pull Age from first Tag and add to the next tag in XSLT.

```
Below is the Desired O/P
    <College>
    <Student> 
            <Name>ABC</Name> 
            <Age>25<Age>
    </Student>
    <Result> 
            <account> 
               <accountNumber>1111</accountNumber> 
               <Age>25<Age>
            </account> 
            <account> 
               <accountNumber>2222</accountNumber> 
               <Age>25<Age>
            </account> 
    </Result> 
    </College>
```

Current XSLT

```
    <xsl:template match = "Student">
            <Name><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></Name>
            <Age><xsl:value-of select="Age" /></Age>
    </xsl:template> 
    
    <xsl:template match = "Result/account">
      <Student>
        <accountNumber><xsl:value-of select="accountNumber" /></accountNumber>
        <Age></Age> // Not sure how to add this here from earlier tag.
      </Student> 
    </xsl:template>
```

I am unable to use preceding-sibling as the tag isn't present under the same node. Need a way to refer the old node and pick the age value and insert in the new tag.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a **well-formed** XML input example (the one you show does not have a single root element).

Comment: Hi Mike, sry about that. Added the root tag now.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="account">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="accountNumber"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../preceding-sibling::Student[1]/Age"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming there are multiple pairs of `Student` and `Result`, where each `Result` follows the relevant `Student`. Otherwise it could be simpler.